# n-ary (polyadic) group "defined for tuples"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider an n-ary (polyadic) group, which is a generalization of the "usual" ("binary") groups to n-tuples. The definition requires appropriate standard generalizations of associativity and existence of inverse. Can this (or has this?) been generalized to arbitrary tuples? In other words, can the number of factors in the product be made arbitrary (but finite)? What "mathematical object" would this be? Does it have to be induced by some n-ary group or are there examples that are not?

A useful classical paper with the relevant definitions is [Polyadic Groups by Emil Leon Post from 1935 (pdf)](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1940-048-02/S0002-9947-1940-0002894-7/S0002-9947-1940-0002894-7.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I guess if associative law generalizes in the obvious way, the answer is trivial.
Denote group multiplication with brackets, such that e.g. in a binary group $a \cdot b \equiv [ab]$. In the case of an n-ary (polyadic) group, the associative law reads
$$ [[a_1...a_n]a_{n+1}...a_{2n–1}] = [a_1...a_{i}[a_{i+1}...a_{i+n}]a_{i+n+1}...a_{2n–1}] \quad . $$
If one instead allows products of arbitrary arity, it seems that the associative law would generalize to e.g. imply
$$ [abc]=[a[bc]] \quad . $$
Hence, binary multiplication determines multiplication of any arity and every object described in the question would simply be determined by a "usual" binary group.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).